# C# Logical Operator

Tags: c#

Iam Working on an application where I need to get a boolean flag value, `f`, based on the values in two other boolean variables `a` and `b`. The following are the conditions:

1. If both `a` and `b` are true `f` is `true`.
2. If both `a` and `b` are false `f` is `true`.
3. If `a` is true and `b` is false `f` is `true`.
4. If `a` is false and `b` is true `f` is `false`

I'd like to know if there is a simpler way (like a single operator) to obtain the value of f other than what I have:

```
a?true:(b?false:true)
```

Comment: `bool r = a || (!b)`

Comment: Thanks I will try this and get back on whether it is better in performance currently I spend up to 10 sec on a few million records.

Comment: @Lee that should be an answer.

Comment: @Rufw91 optimizing performance is a *different* kind of question. Reducing the number of operands isn't going to improve performance as much as parallel execution. You can use eg PLINQ to add the simplified expression to the `.Where()` clause to search your data using all cores, eg :`myContainer.AsParallel().Where(rec=>rec.a || (!rec.b)).ToList()`. Simpler expressions make parallelization easier

Comment: Yea I found out there was no change in performance :). Ok I will try PLINQ

Answer (score 9):

`a ? true : cond` is equivalent to `a || cond` and `b ? false : true` is the same as `!b` so you can use:

```
bool result = a || !b;
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you looking for is Logical Implication in inverse Direction:

```
a<=b

a    1 1 0 0 
b    1 0 1 0
a<=b 1 1 0 1
```

Edit:I didn't give good explanation on my answer, regarding C# explanation and what actually Logical Implication is:

First, the => is the formal symbol for *if...then*.

> P => Q means 
>   If P then Q.

Logical implication is rather intuitive, because we can transfer it most cases to natural language. Example:

> If n>3, then n+1 >3

which is obviously true.

Bare something in mind - 
Citing *Logical Reasoning: First Course*:

In ordinary language, 'if...then' has a double meaning. Imagine that you say 'If it is raining, then I will not come'. Often this also means 'But if it is not raining, then I will come.It is true that you have not uttered this last sentence, however, a little common sense can lead to the conclusion of the last sentence.

There is a very good explanation on how to use Logical Implication In C# on this link : https://ericlippert.com/2015/11/05/logical-implication/

Furthermore,
Lee's Answer is indeed correct. 
Logical implication in format

> a=>b in C# is (!a || b)

Hence, answer to the question will be

> a<=b in C# is (a||!b)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. There is no `<=` operator in C#

Comment: Hope it could have helped him anyway. And as I see Lee gave the wanted answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos there *is* a `<=` operator... it just means something else ;)

Comment: The answer clearly lack explanation. What is `P`, what is `<=` and what is `Q` as well as how this works and actually `c#` code (it's tagged with c#). Pseudo-code is somewhat fine, only math - nope.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque should have said `no such logical operator`

Comment: @Archilius in this case you should have added a comment. If you can't don't post the comment as an answer. There is a reason for the rule that requires 50 rep before commenting. People need to familiarize themselves with Q&A and understand what is a good answer and what is a comment

Answer (score 0):

When I broke down your rules into simpler terms, I got:

1. if `a == b`, `f` is `true`
2. otherwise, `f == a`

So, one simple form of this expression would be:

```
f = (a == b) || a
```